# Custom "Content Query" web part formatting in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

What is best and easiest way to format a "Content Query" web part in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

This article explains how to customize the CQWP using SharePoint 2010 without any code and deployment:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756834/Customizing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-and-Item-St

this article explains the steps to use customized XSL style sheets:
http://www.cwheeler76.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)